# Array iteration with for loop - use of conditional statements and returns

Tags: javascript

For this array of objects:

```
var contacts = [
  {
      "firstName": "Akira",
      "lastName": "Laine",
      "number": "0543236543",
      "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
  },
  {
      "firstName": "Harry",
      "lastName": "Potter",
      "number": "0994372684",
      "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
  },
  {
      "firstName": "Sherlock",
      "lastName": "Holmes",
      "number": "0487345643",
      "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
  },
  {
      "firstName": "Kristian",
      "lastName": "Vos",
      "number": "unknown",
      "likes": ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
  }
];
```

There is then a `for` loop that iterates over the array of objects, and the arguments to lookup against the object. I understand that we are iterating and that the function will stop running after it `returns` something. I have included a `console.log(i);` to see the value of the iterator variable, to see how many times the loop occurs.

```
function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {  

    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {  
      console.log(i);
      if (contacts[i].firstName === name) {  
        if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {         
          return contacts[i][prop]   
        } else {
          return "No such property"; 
        }
      }

    } //end of loop
  return "No such contact"; 
  }


   console.log(lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName")); // Vos
```

So I run the code and look at my console output and get what I expect, we iterate 4 times, and then we `return` the current objects property.

[image]

Why is that the code does not work when I refactor the function, so that rather than having two nested `if` conditions, I use the logical AND operator `&&` which combines the two test conditions into one `if` statement - like so:

```
function lookUpProfile(name, prop) { 
  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {  
    console.log(i);
    if (contacts[i].firstName === name && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {                 
      return contacts[i][prop]   
    } else {
      return "No such property"; 
    }

  } //end of loop
  return "No such contact"; 
}

 console.log(lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName")); // Expected output: Vos
```

Now when I run the code, no iteration seems to occur as `console.log(i);` seems to output `undefined` once and not multiple times, so we don't seem to be looping and I don't understand why. Secondly even though our test conditions are met we return 'no such property'.

[image]

What I need to understand if why this simple refactor has broken the function. I understand that once a function returns something that function execution ends and iteration would stop, I think this issue has something to do with being outside of the loop and the control flow breaking but I don't understand why. Please can someone clearly explain why this is happening in my specific case.

Answer (score 1):

when you have nested if condition

```
if (contacts[i].firstName === name)
```

this checks for name if name doesn't matches it doesn't do anything

but in second one you have return in else statement after if so in case name doesn't matches it return from function

```
 if (contacts[i].firstName === name && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {                 
      return contacts[i][prop]   
    } else {                           // problem is here
  return "No such property"; 
 }
```

---

just remove the else condition from loop

```js
var contacts = [{"firstName": "Akira","lastName": "Laine","number": "0543236543","likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]},{"firstName": "Harry","lastName": "Potter","number": "0994372684","likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]},{"firstName": "Sherlock","lastName": "Holmes","number": "0487345643","likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]},{"firstName": "Kristian","lastName": "Vos","number": "unknown","likes": ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]}];


function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    if (contacts[i].firstName === name && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      return contacts[i][prop]
    }
  } //end of loop
  return "No such contact";
}

console.log(lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in your previous code, `"No such property"` was returned only if `contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)` was `false`. Now, it is also returned if `contacts[i].firstName === name` is false. You want to keep those 2 `if` blocks separated.

Also, the reason why your `console.log(i)` prints `undefined` is because it is above your `for` loop, before the declaration of the `i` variable. Move it down 1 line.